# Magento 2: "All in Column" does not work if actions column is not present in the grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, grid, massaction

I have built a custom grid where I have only 3 columns, i.e. **Category** and **Priority**, and the **Mass Action** column.

Since the priority field is the only field which can be changed, so I don't want **Edit** action in the grid.

Now the problem is that if the **Actions** column is not present in the grid, the field "**All in Column**" does not work in the mass edit action.

[image: All in Column Image]

This functionality does not work, because the **Apply** button becomes hidden if the **Actions** column is not visible in the grid.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: custom grid using UI component?

Comment: yes, it is custom grid using UI components.

Comment: Have you try with this `<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>`

Comment: Where should I use above code?

Comment: @ChiragPatel, I tried to use your code in the Actions column, but it did not work. using **`componentDisabled`** hides the column and due to this, I am at the same place where I started my question. :)

Comment: Can you share your `actionColumn` code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85687/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-mohit-kumar-arora).

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code. i used in my custom module. and it's working.

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Namespace\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ImageActions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
```

Before add code column is showing.

[image]

After add code column is hide.

[image]

I hope it helps!

Comment: My problem is not hiding or showing the column. My problem is that when I hide the **Actions** column, the mass action field **All in column** does not work. This is because the **Apply** button also hides when we hide/remove the **Actions** column from the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. My solution is maintaining action column with a "small" label like "_":

```
<actionsColumn name="actions">
  <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="label" xsi:type="string">_</item>
      <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
      <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
    </item>
  </argument>
</actionsColumn>
```

It's not the best, but could not make it work without actionsColumn.