# delete columns from grid customers

Tags: magento2, customer-grid

I added the sequence module_customer to my layout module and overrided the **customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="*/*/new"/>
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true">Add New Customer</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <spinner>customer_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>customer_listing.customer_listing_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="customer_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Magento_Customer::manage</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider" name="customer_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <settings>
            <sticky>true</sticky>
        </settings>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters"/>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
            <action name="delete">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure to delete selected customers?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="customer/index/massDelete"/>
                    <type>delete</type>
                    <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="subscribe">
                <settings>
                    <url path="customer/index/massSubscribe"/>
                    <type>subscribe</type>
                    <label translate="true">Subscribe to Newsletter</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="unsubscribe">
                <settings>
                    <confirm>
                        <message translate="true">Are you sure to unsubscribe selected customers from newsletter?</message>
                        <title translate="true">Unsubscribe from Newsletter</title>
                    </confirm>
                    <url path="customer/index/massUnsubscribe"/>
                    <type>unsubscribe</type>
                    <label translate="true">Unsubscribe from Newsletter</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="assign_to_group">
                <settings>
                    <type>assign_to_group</type>
                    <label translate="true">Assign a Customer Group</label>
                    <actions class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\MassAction\Group\Options"/>
                </settings>
            </action>
            <action name="edit">
                <settings>
                    <callback>
                        <target>editSelected</target>
                        <provider>customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns_editor</provider>
                    </callback>
                    <type>edit</type>
                    <label translate="true">Edit</label>
                </settings>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <settings>
            <editorConfig>
                <param name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="customer/index/inlineEdit"/>
                    <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </param>
                <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</param>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns.ids</param>
            </editorConfig>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customer_listing.customer_listing.customer_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="10">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id" sortOrder="20">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">ID</label>
                <sorting>asc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="name" sortOrder="30">
            <settings>
                <controlVisibility>false</controlVisibility>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="email" sortOrder="40">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Email</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="group_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="50">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Group</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_telephone" sortOrder="60">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Phone</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_postcode" sortOrder="70">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">ZIP</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_country_id" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="80">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Country</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_region" sortOrder="90">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">State/Province</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="100">
            <settings>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Customer Since</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="website_id" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Websites" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="110">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Web Site</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="confirmation" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Confirmation" sortOrder="130">
            <settings>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Confirmed email</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="created_in" sortOrder="140">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Account Created in</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_full" sortOrder="150">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Billing Address</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="shipping_full" sortOrder="160">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Shipping Address</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="dob" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="170">
            <settings>
                <timezone>false</timezone>
                <dateFormat>MMM d, y</dateFormat>
                <skipTimeZoneConversion>true</skipTimeZoneConversion>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Date of Birth</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="taxvat" sortOrder="180">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Tax VAT Number</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="gender" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select" sortOrder="190">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <controlVisibility>false</controlVisibility>
                <label translate="true">Gender</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_street" sortOrder="200">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Street Address</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_city" sortOrder="210">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">City</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_fax" sortOrder="220">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Fax</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_vat_id" sortOrder="230">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">VAT Number</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_company" sortOrder="240">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Company</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_firstname" sortOrder="250">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Billing Firstname</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="billing_lastname" sortOrder="260">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>text</editorType>
                </editor>
                <label translate="true">Billing Lastname</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="lock_expires" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\AccountLock" sortOrder="270">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Account Lock</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

And I created this upgradeData

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace BO\Client\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Directory\Model\AllowedCountries;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\FieldDataConverterFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\DataConverter\SerializedToJson;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AllowedCountries
     */
    private $allowedCountriesReader;

    /**
     * @var IndexerRegistry
     */
    protected $indexerRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
     */
    protected $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var FieldDataConverterFactory
     */
    private $fieldDataConverterFactory;

    /**
     *@param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param FieldDataConverterFactory|null $fieldDataConverterFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        FieldDataConverterFactory $fieldDataConverterFactory = null
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;

        $this->fieldDataConverterFactory = $fieldDataConverterFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            FieldDataConverterFactory::class
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $entityAttributes = [
            'customer' => [
                'website_id' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
                'created_in' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                ],
                'email' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                ],
                'group_id' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
                'dob' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
                'taxvat' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
                'confirmation' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
                'created_at' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
                'gender' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
            ],
            'customer_address' => [
                'company' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                ],
                'street' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                ],
                'city' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                ],
                'country_id' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
                'region' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                ],
                'region_id' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
                'postcode' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
                'telephone' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
                ],
                'fax' => [
                    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
            ],
        ];

        foreach ($entityAttributes as $entityType => $attributes) {
            foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode => $attributeData) {
                $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute($entityType, $attributeCode);
                foreach ($attributeData as $key => $value) {
                    $attribute->setData($key, $value);
                }
                $attribute->save();
            }
        }


        $indexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get(Customer::CUSTOMER_GRID_INDEXER_ID);
        $indexer->reindexAll();
        $this->eavConfig->clear();
        $setup->endSetup();
    }


}
```

But nothing changed I still have the columns ?????? 
Please help me and thanks.

Comment: Do you want delete column or hide column?

Comment: ok if i hide them they will appear when i export the csv file

Comment: but his there a way to hide them  not manually but by code so that they don't appear in csv file when exporting the list

Comment: clear cache and disable it.

Comment: done but nothing changed

Comment: I am not sure about it will not display in export file but if you want to hide any column from grid then try this way https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248514/magento-2-all-in-column-does-not-work-if-actions-column-is-not-present-in-the/249824?noredirect=1#comment351662_249824

Comment: i tried to export and they still there

Comment: Too fast :) have you checked or try my answer?

Comment: yes of course  brother

Comment: Have you try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151966/admin-grid-remove-columns-from-export?

Comment: no i didi not try that

Comment: but still i have to hide them by code

Comment: so that the administarteur can't see them even in the colunums (eye)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85730/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-developper-magento).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the above code, where I remove two fields of admin customer's grid:

```
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="gender">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="dob">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
```